# How to have mocha watch source/project files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, mocha.js

I would like to have Mocha watch my source/project files and NOT the test files. how can I accomplish this? Also the test files and source/project files are in different directories. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think this tutorial can help you :
https://dev.to/promyze/setup-mocha-in-watch-mode-for-tdd-in-node-js-1mah

You can just update the paths to follow, or add the `--watch-ignore` options in the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

`mocha --watch` watches the current working directory.

If you'd like more felxibility you can use:

```
npm install -g watch
watch 'mocha' dir_to_watch
```